# Can a 41mm shock be replaced in Bajaj Pulsar 150 by removing the company fitted one?

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, pulsar

Can the OEM shock be replaced on a 2008 Pulsar 150?  I would like to remove the OEM shock and replace it with a 41mm aftermarket model.

Answer (score 2):

The stock shock can be replaced on your motorcycle.  Indicating that you want to use a 41mm replacement, I am unsure of fitment and could not say.

There are several manufacturers that offer replacement rear shocks, they are usually relatively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Bajaj shocks are really cheap, maybe $20. You can get them wherever the bikes are sold (in Asia). As far as length, I am unsure what the length is on stock shocks, you can measure them with a tape measure. If the length is slightly longer or shorter, you will be fine, it will just change the ride a bit. This is an Indian 150 4-stroke, not an 1100CC race bike. Try it out and see how it goes!